# How to remove dot?

Tags: php, regex

I have this code :

```
$value = 'daryaa-manmarziyan-(VideoStatus.Net).mp4';
$final_value = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]/", "", $value);
echo $final_value; exit();
```

Output is : `daryaamanmarziyanVideoStatus.Net.mp4`

I want output `daryaamanmarziyanVideoStatusNet.mp4`

All unnecessary dot(.) will remove What can i do ?

Comment: In your regex remove the `.` but that would remove all dots, the one before mp4 included

Comment: Is the filename always hardcoded? Or is this just an example and can the filename be pretty much anything?. In the first.. Solution should be obvious.. Second is more interesting.

Comment: @Loek file name will come different all time.. i just get problem while testing but need solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to use

```
$value = 'daryaa-manmarziyan-(VideoStatus.Net).mp4';
$fileNames = preg_replace(array("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]/", "/\.(?=.*\.)/"), "", $fileName);
echo $final_value; exit();
```

Output will come

```
daryaamanmarziyanVideoStatusNet.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your `preg_replace` call to this:

```
$final_value = preg_replace(array("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]/", "/\.(?=.*\.)/"), "", $value);
```

The second replace string (`/\.(?=.*\.)/`) looks for a `.` which is followed by another `.` and replaces that with an empty string.

Output for your sample data:

```
daryaamanmarziyanVideoStatusNet.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex with an alternation:

```
preg_replace("/[^\w.]+|\.(?=[^.]*\.)/", "", $value);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [PHP demo online](https://ideone.com/MwaWRx) and an [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dhvyXb/1).

The `\.(?=[^.]*\.)` pattern matches any `.` with `\.` that is followed with any 0+ chars other than `.` followed with `.`.

Also, `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is equal to `\w` if you do not use the `u` modifier, thus, you may shorten the pattern a bit.

**Details**

- `[^\w.]+` - 1 or more chars other than word (`A-Za-z0-9_`) chars and `.`
- `|` - or
- `\.` - a dot...
- `(?=[^.]*\.)` - (a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, makes sure that dot is) followed with

  - `[^.]*` - 0+ chars other than `.`
  - `\.` - a dot.